# Why do I get certificate error when connecting to "trusted PEAP server?"

Tags: windows-server-2008, certificate, wifi, certificate-authority, peap

I'm trying to connect *Windows 7* machine to my wireless network secured with **WPA2-Enterprise PEAP**.
PEAP uses **server authentication** so I have created **root CA** named **FesbCA** on my *Windows server 2008 R2* and with it I signed **root.fesb.hr** certificate which is used for server authentication.

On Windows 7 client machine **root CA FesbCA** is imported to **Trusted Root Certification Authorities** and that should make **root.fesb.hr valid certificate**.

Than why do I still get the certificate error when trying to connect to wireless network?

Here is reference [image with error](http://content.screencast.com/users/IvanMacek/folders/Jing/media/b535285d-d13d-4825-8f47-c89ba8070a6f/2012-01-09_0157.png).

Comment: Does the NPS server (root) have FesbCA's certificate in its store as well? BTW, I think some are being misled by the names of your servers. Typically, in a PKI the root is the self-signed root CA. In this case, root.fesb.hr is simply a RADIUS box and FesbCA is the root CA correct?

Answer (score 1):

Export the root certificate from the CA (FesbCA) and import it to the Trusted Root Certification Authority store

Comment: I did that, notice the second paragraph:
"On Windows 7 client machine root CA FesbCA is imported to Trusted Root Certification Authorities and that should make root.fesb.hr valid certificate."

Comment: In the current user store or in the computer account store? If you open up the Certificates mmc snap-in for "My Account" and find the root.fesb.hr certificate, and double click it, what does it state under the "Details" tab? Can it locate the chain in its entirety?

Comment: There isn't **root.fesb.hr** there is only **FesbCA** _My User Account_ certification store. Certification chain is: **FesbCA -> root.fesb.hr**.